# How to search between two dates in month and day only in access database with datetimepicker c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a birthday report in datagridview in MS Access database.
for example :

1. 4/5/2006
2. 4/5/2002
   If Today Date is 4/5/2021
   If I want to search between 4/5 and 4/5
   `adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Today); adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", DateTime.Today);`
   It will give nothing ... what should I do ?
   All code :

   ````
       OleDbDataAdapter da;
       DataTable dt;

       void FillAllRecords()
       {

           con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbService.accdb");
           da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM service", con);
           dt = new DataTable();
           con.Open();
           da.Fill(dt);
           con.Close();
           dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
       }

       void FilterRecords()
       {

           con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=dbService.accdb");
           con.Open();
           string sql = "SELECT *  FROM service Where p_date BETWEEN @date1 and @date2";
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Today);
            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", DateTime.Today);
           adp.Fill(dt);
           con.Close();
           dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
       }
          private void btnLoad2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           FillAllRecords();
           datetimepicker1.Visible = true;
           datetimepicker2.Visible = true;
           label1.Visible = true;
           label2.Visible = true;
           button1.Visible = true;
           btnLoad2.Visible = false;

       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           FilterRecords();
       }
       private void btnAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           FillAllRecords();
       }```
   ````

Comment: I'd try `adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);`

Answer (score 0):

OleDB doesn't use named parameters in the query string, it uses positional parameters. So change your query string as follows:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM service Where p_date BETWEEN ? and ?";
```

Just remember to add the parameters in the order they appear in the query.

Comment: You can name your parameters, not just use `?` . What's important is the order in which the parameters are added, but you can use any name (in `Parameters.Add()` and in the query string).

Comment: Yes, you can name the parameters whatever you want, but in the query string you must use '?'. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.selectcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: No, you don't need to. You can use the name set in the Parameter. Just test it.

Comment: From the MS Docs: The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: *does not support named parameters* means that the names you assign are not taken into consideration, just their position. So, you can use whatever names you like, without any specific syntax -- **Just test it**.

Comment: Which is exactly what I've been saying from the start. You can name the parameters whatever you want, but the query string must use '?' as placeholders for where the parameters will be used.

Comment: Nope, the query string can use **any name you like** -- Why don't you test it? It's not that difficult.

Comment: Again, from the MS Docs *In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.* I have tested it.

Comment: One of the main projects I maintain uses OleDB for database access. I write a lot of parameterised queries. I have to use '?'. If it can be done another way then I suggest you request MS edit the documentation to state otherwise.

Comment: You don't **have to** use it, you simply did use it. Maybe because you read those documents. Since you already have at least one MS Access database ready for testing, set the provider to `Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;` or `Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.16.0;` (not Jet 4.0) and **test it**.